# Which driver is necessary to show the touchpad-disable option?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, mouse, touchpad

It seems that I accidentally removed a driver/software to enable the option to automatically disable the touchpad when a mouse is plugged in (explained in detail [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/34075-windows-automatically-disable-the-touchpad-of-your-laptop-when-a-usb-mouse-is-connected)). My Mouse settings currently look like this:

[image]

To the right, there should be a tab or something - but it's not there. How can I bring back the tab with the option to disable my touchpad? I'm running Windows 8.1 64x on a Samsung laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what they're showing/telling you in the article you linked, and what you're showing us, you need to install the driver provided by your touchpad's manufacturer for that tab to appear.  For example, this article is talking specifically about ELAN and Synaptics touchpads, and as noted by the custom icon on the tab in the example, it's a 3rd party add-on to Windows by the touchpad manufacturer.

[image]

Look up your notebook's model on Samsung's support site and grab the touchpad drivers they offer.  If the tab doesn't appear after installing them, then your touchpad may simply not support that feature.